# Estimating the interruption rate of a mixed poisson process.

Tags: probability, poisson-process, mixing

For a regular Poisson process, we know that the inter-arrival distribution, $T$ is exponential with rate $\lambda$ and the number of events in any interval, $N(t)$ is Poisson with mean $\lambda t$ and variance $\lambda t$ as well. Let's say we observe the process for a certain amount of time, $t$. The unbiased estimator of $\lambda$ will become:

$$\hat{\lambda} = \frac{N(t)}{t}$$

The expected value of this estimator is: $E(\hat{\lambda}) = \frac{E(N(t))}{t} = \lambda$ as expected.

And the variance of this estimator will be:

$$V(\hat{\lambda}) = \frac{V(N(t))}{t^2} = \frac{\lambda}{t}$$ and this is encouraging since for a large timeframe of observation, the variance in this estimator will go to $0$.

Now, I want to consider a Mixed Poisson process, described in section 5.4.3 of Ross' [*Introduction to Probability Models*](https://fac.ksu.edu.sa/sites/default/files/introduction-to-probability-model-s.ross-math-cs.blog_.ir_.pdf). It is a regular Poisson process when conditioned on some distribution $L(\lambda)$ of the rate, $\lambda$. Now, we're still interested in calculating the average hazard rate of this process. It's clear by definition (conditional on $L$, we get the regular Poisson process):

$$E(N(t)|L)=Lt$$
$$V(N(t)|L)=Lt$$

Using the law of total expectation:

$$E(N(t)) = t E(L)$$
Using the law of total variance:

$$V(N(t))=E(V(N(t)|L))+V(E(N(t)|L))$$
$$=E(Lt)+V(Lt)$$
$$=tE(L)+t^2V(L)$$

This means that if we observe this process for a large period of time, $t$, we can estimate the average hazard rate:

$$\hat{\lambda} = \frac{N(t)}{t} $$
$$=>E(\hat{\lambda})= E(L)$$

And the variance of this estimator becomes:

$$V(\hat{\lambda}) = \frac{V(N(t))}{t^2} = \frac{E(L)}{t}+V(L)$$

Now, this is worrying since no matter how large $t$ becomes, the variance of the estimator, $\hat{\lambda}$ never goes to zero. Is there a different way then, to estimate $E(\hat{\lambda}) = E(L)$ where we can be sure that given a large enough time-frame of observation, we will get an unbiased estimator with variance tending to zero?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a conceptual problem rather than a question of finding a better estimator. You can't reduce the variance of $\hat\lambda$ below $V(L)$, since by definition the rate depends on $L$ and without any information about $L$ you don't know the exact rate.

I get the impression that what you're actually trying to do is perhaps to estimate the rate of a given instance of the process with arbitrary precision. You can do that using your estimator. Its variance doesn't reflect uncertainty about the rate in any given instance of the process, but uncertainty about which rate the process will have.

For instance, in Example $5.30$ on p. $353$ of the text you linked to, you can determine the claim rate of any given customer to arbitrary precision by observing them for long enough. But the variance you calculated is the variance over all customers.

Comment: This helps. But I am trying to measure the average rate across the entire population, not just an individual. We literally have a KPI at work which is defined as such (for failure rate across a group of machines). If the process of failures across the entire group were mixed poisson, I want to have an estimator for $E(L)$ that becomes arbitrarily precise given enough observed machine time. Is this impossible?

Comment: @RohitPandey: If the KPI is the failure rate across a group of machines, you have to measure it across the group of machines. You can't just sample one machine and hope that the variance is reduced over time, since it's not related to time but to the variance among the machines. If you average your estimator over all the machines, you'll get a much lower variance.

Comment: Yes, we do look at failures for a group and total machine time across the group. This leads to an unbiased estimator for the average across the group. Problem with this estimator is, the variance doesn't go to zero with large machine hours observed when dealing with a mixed poisson.

Comment: @RohitPandey: The $\hat\lambda$ that you calculate in the question isn't averaged across a group of machines. It's an estimator for a single mixed Poisson process, i.e. a single machine randomly chosen from the group of machines. If you average over the group of machines, the variance will be less than $V(L)$.

Comment: @RohitPandey: You're "averaging over the machines" in the sense that you randomly select one according to the distribution of $L$, and thus the expected rate is the average rate across the machines -- but you're not "averaging over the machines" in the sense of observing all of them -- you're only dealing with one process of one (randomly selected) machine, and hence you're not reducing the variance as you would if you observed all machines and averaged the results. (I'm talking about what you wrote down here; not about what you may actually be doing at work, which may of course be different.)

Comment: You bring up good points. At work, we have the data for every machine on terms of how long it ran, and how many failures it had. We aggregate the total failures we see over some period of time across all machines and call it $n$. Then we aggregate the run time across all and call it $t$. We then estimate the failure rate for the group of machines as $\frac n t$. I see why the variance of this estimator can't be less than $E(L)$ since what if we sample just one machine. I guess if we guarantee we got enough machine observation time from all of them, the variance should go down.

Comment: @RohitPandey If you aggregate the run time across all machines, then you can make the variance arbitrarily small. That's just not what you've written down here.

Comment: Right, the $N(t)$ and $t$ in the question are both for a group of machines. I can edit to make that clear. The $\hat{\lambda}$ we are estimating is also for the whole group. I guess the question is, how much of the $t$ comes from machine 1 and how much from machine 2 and so on. We could have some short lived machines from which we just couldn't get enough observation time.